# How to clear all data in datagridview and it would not effect in delete data

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

How do I clear all data and not delete data or column in datagridview? I want to clear the data first and query on the result to make the result not duplicate.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "clear all data" - how does that differ from deleting data?

Comment: when i want see my result. 
for example:
"SELECT ColumnID,columnDesc from columns where groupDesc = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"
i want query this to my result and it occur some duplicate result in my datagridview, than i need to clear it first and then just run the query to avoid my result occur previous result.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that I understand what you asked, but yet -
Clearing all rows from *DataGridView* is very simple:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
```

Regarding the query duplicates, you can use *SELECT DISTINCT*.
And another thing: I hope your code is only a simplified example, because it is highly exposed to [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: This will give an error "Cannot clear this list".

Answer (score 3):

If you are binding your DataGridView through code that is, using `DataSource` property you can clear DataGridView using the following code.

`dataGridView1.DataSource=null;`

It will not delete data from your database,just clear your DataGridView.

Answer (score 1):

in vb.net you can use :

datagridview1.Datasource = nothing

but it will empty your datagridview1 and initialize it to default.

Comment: This wipes the datagrid columns as well, while as sugested bellow, dataGridView.DataSource.Clear() will only remove the content and leave the columns and settings as are. So if you don't load your columns everytime you load data (which shouldn't be done) it is not a good method.

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify Sujith's to the following:

> DataGridView1.DataSource = DBNull.Value

Answer (score 1):

If datagrid is bound data you should do:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = null;
dataGridView.DataSource.Clear();
```

If datagrid is unbound data no need to null the datasource:

```
dataGridView.DataSource.Clear();
```

Another trick is:

```
 dt.Columns.Clear();
 dt.Rows.Clear();
 dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that it will clear all the states, then the following code can be used:

```
dataGridView.CancelEdit()
dataGridView.Columns.Clear()
dataGridView.DataSource = Nothing
dataGridView.Rows.Clear()
```